# How to sum the columns counts of the same table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, count, sum

I have a table with 4 columns, I need to SUM the COUNT of each one.

I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Is absolute basic, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  What does "sum the count" mean to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(Col1) + Count(Col2) + Count(Col3) + Count(Col4) as Total FROM *Table*
```

Adds the Counts of all 4 columns together. That should do the trick for you.